# Allow only user defined javascript blocks and hide the rest of the javascript

Tags: javascript, php

how can I allow only certain parts of javascript code?

On the server I have defined roles admin, writer,....

Everybody will get access to different js functionalities.
Therefore I require to pass permission for the role.
However what is the best option to do that?
I know I could do it this way. It would work. However for me it looks dirty, since it will have plenty of programming language code changes from php to js to php to js ...

```
<?php 
if(Role('Admin')){
?><script>
JS Admin script....
</script><?php
};; ?>
```

Does someone know a better solution?
Maybe there is an option to pass a parameter from php to js so that the javascript code stays in javascript and is not flipping multiple times.

Comment: I'd consolidate all the scripts into one (probably with a bundler like Webpack), then do the permissions verification on the *backend* to check whether the user is a permitted admin or writer etc. Client-side JS is for functionality, but not for security.

Comment: @CertainPerformance pls confirm if I understood it correctly. So you mean the best is to save for every permission one file? Afterwards I just require to call the file with the correct permission. Is this correct?

Comment: It should not be the main goal to restrict the JavaScript. The server (PHP code in this case) needs to perform access validation before doing things like read or write operations in files or databases. In your case I would have normal user.js and a admin.js on top included when user has Admin role granted. Remember: JavaScript is always visible in the browser.

Comment: @MarkusZeller thanks. My experience showed that it is not always visible. For example in a restricted path. Afterwards js can be loaded for the page but even a code can not see the js. Or am I wrong and the code can be seen of loaded js code with restricted path?

Comment: If you send JavaScript to the browser every user can see it via source inspection or network tab. How should it be executed, when the browser has no access? So even if you restrict the js files on a path accessible only when admin role granted, it is there in the browser. Again, the server should always be responsible to verify if the taken actions are allowed.

Comment: @MarkusZeller yes you might be right. I know the file is loaded, however you can not visit the path like "Open in new tab", however there might be a way to load the content via the console.

Comment: Golden rule: JavaScript is never secret or invisible to the user. Via `sources` inspector tab I can see all files the browser requested with all it contents. No tricks, no console magic.